# Agda which data type to use to model a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, agda

In Agda, I'm trying to write some data types with some functions acting on them. These will be compiled to javascript to be used to verify the logic of the state of an app. In order to do this, I will need a data type that compiles to a javascript array. I need to do some filtering as well as getting the max value of the array.

On the Agda side I would like to prove some properties of this data type (that will compile to the javascript array). From the `std-lib`, can `Vec` be used to model a javascript array? Are there any other options (like `Vec.Bounded` or something)?

I originally tried using a `Data.List` but had a proof that involved getting the last element, so I opted to switch to `Data.Vec` in order not to have to deal with a `Data.Maybe`.

Later I wanted to `filter` out some elements and found that `Data.Vec.filter` has the signature:

```
filter : ∀ {n} → Vec A n → Vec≤ A n
```

After filtering out the elements I need to cast the `Vec≤` back to a `Vec`.

I'm wondering at this point if I shouldn't switch to using `Vec≤` in order not to need to deal with casting between `Vec≤` and `Vec`.

What are the trade-offs involved between these different data types when compiling to javascript? Do `List`, `Vec` and `Vec≤` actually just all compile to a javascript array? Also, is `Vec≤` a superset of the others in the sense that it supports the functionalities of `List` and `Vec`?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

What's really "sticking [out] to me, here," is the word: *Javascript.*

How, exactly, do you intend to "convert [...] into Javascript **code** ... in order to get a Javascript **data-type** ... (an array) ..."

... ... I'm lost as to where you're actually going.  Or, think you're going with this.

Comment: I mean using Agda's javascript backend (https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1.1/tools/compilers.html?highlight=backend#javascript-backend)